# Why constructor ambiguity applicable to Wrapper class only

Tags: java

While I was trying to generate constructor ambiguity, I found that when I use primitive types, eclipse does not throw me error. However it throws error while I use wrapper class.

```
public class SubClass {

    public SubClass(Integer i) {

        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public SubClass(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

If I use int instead of Integer, which is a wrapper class then constructor ambiguity error disappears. It then calls constructor with parameter of String type.

Could you please elaborate this.

Thanks.

Comment: in what case you got ambiguity here ? `null` ?

Comment: ambiguous null argument - `new SubClass(null)`

Comment: Can you explain the clause with supporting examples to make it more clear?

Comment: Yes in case of null.

I have following code of main class which gives me error in eclipse.




public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SubClass s = new SubClass(null);
    }
}

Comment: Just define void constructor, then

Comment: @Cast_A_Way Is `null` a valid value for `int`?

Answer (score 1):

because in case of `int` it can autobox to Integer and choose the right constructor version, there is no straight path from `int` to `String` so it is never an option

in case of `null` both constructor are eligible and so the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

As the primitive data types cannot be assigned with null value, it resolves the constructor, saying that it is `SubClass(Stirng xx)` is used and not `SubClass(int a)`.

If the Constructor takes Objects where Integer can be assigned with null, It cannot resolve the constructor.

So it throws error.

To add to the answer,

```
int a = null; // gives compilation issue
Integer a = null;; // no compilation issue

Integer a = null;
int x = a; // throws null pointer exception at runtime.
```

Which looks at runtime only.

Comment: Thank you all.
Now I got the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SubClass(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

`public SubClass(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }`

If I replace Integer with Object, then why don't we get ambiguity issue.

Comment: The Object is the parent class of all classes, so we should use Object class there.